# Getting R square value from ctree

Tags: r

Is there a way to retrieve the R square value from a `ctree` model? Or is this impossible with how the function runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so -- however you can extract predictions using `predict(your_model)` and just calculate it on your own.

Comment: Could you continue to explain what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: Scott, I think @mbq is referring to the fact that $R^2 = {\rm cor}({\rm predicted \ values}, {\rm actual \ values})^2$