# Classification Tree Analysis - Assessment of tree explanatory power (R-square?) using the party package in R

Tags: r, cart, r-squared

I have produced a model using the `ctree` function in R, and want to know whether this tree is actually explaining my data well.

I am trying to explain the presence or absence of landscape disturbances using environmental factors. `rpart` gives an $R^2$ value, but since my data are not well-balanced (PRESENCE contains a relatively small number of 1s), I believe the `ctree` model will work better. A (simplified) version of my model is:

```
fit <- ctree (PRESENCE ~ A + B + C + D + E + F, data=dat);
```

where PRESENCE is a factor containing values of (0,1), 
five of the independent variables (denoted by the letters A-F) are 
numerical values (environmental data),
and the remaining variable is categorical.

I believe there is a way to make an $R^2$ value using the `predict` function (as in [Getting R square value from ctree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23772/getting-r-square-value-from-ctree)), but I'm fairly new to R and haven't had any success trying to code this.

Comment: This question opens up the broader, and potentially more useful to you, question of whether $R^2$ is an appropriate metric for a classification model.  Typically we'd avoid regression (`rpart`) for binary outcomes and resort to classification, as you've done; the metrics of choice for classification are mostly variants or transforms of the fraction of 1s your model identified as such and the fraction of 0s your model identified as 1s.  Are you sure that $R^2$ is what you want or need?

Comment: Adding to comments from @jbowman : can you just use the % misclassified from the error matrix?